# Selection of row in multiple UITableView in one UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have multiple `UITableview`s in one `UIView`.

How can I achieve the following:

> If a row is selected in one table, the row in the other tables will be
>   selected, too.

Will that go in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: Can you show me code within - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method?

Comment: You want to show just a selection OR perform an action, too. If want to perform an action, then this approach will create a mess.

Comment: oh.,i was trying to achieve a gridtable, so i made mutiple tableviews,,guess i have to change approach..

Comment: For implementing Grid Table : Try http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I might be misinterpreting the question, as there are three answers about finding out which table view is used. But what you want is to select the same row in all of the table views, no?
Then use:

`– selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`.

for all your tableviews in `didSelectRow:atIndexPath:`

Comment: yeah,,same row in all of the tables..sorry for the confusion

Comment: right now., i was able to scroll them altogether.,, i also want to do it in their rows,,,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Well in the delegate itself returns the tableview reference where action is performed
So to check set the outlets for the tableview and compare to find which tableview has action performed

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Here `tableView` is the table in which the action occoured

Answer (score -1):

Just use tableView parameter:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So, all you need is just compare tableView variable:

```
if (tableView == self.tableView1)
...
else if (tableView == self.tableView2)
...
```